# How to gitignore this "test-output" folder?

Tags: git, eclipse, github, ignore

I edited the **gitignore** so i can ignore both  "**test-output**" folder and also **classes.html** inside that folder:

[image]

As I see its not working. So how to do this?

Comment: `ID/test-output` without starting `/` and/or `ID/` is missing on the third line

Comment: If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. [[source](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)]. Therefore, add `ID/` in line 3.

Comment: In the _Git Staging_ view you can just right-click and choose _Ignore_ to `.gitignore` a file. If you edit the `.gitignore` outside of Eclipse (your screenshot shows that you used _Notepad_), you have to hit the _Refresh_ (F5) button to see the changes. Be aware that each folder can have its own `.gitignore` file and the paths are relative to the directory containing the `.gitignore` file (`/foo/` ignores the `foo` folder contained in the same directory than the `.gitignore` file; `foo/` ignores all `foo` folders somewhere nested in the directory containing the `.gitignore` file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have the leading `/` in the path:

```
ID/test-output
```

Comment: Why? There is major difference between `/ID` and `ID` but there is no difference between `/ID/test-output` and `ID/test-output`. From [`git help ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format): "***If there is a separator** at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then **the pattern is relative to the directory level** of the particular `.gitignore` file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.*" — emphasize mine

Comment: @MThomasMary Then why have you accepted the answer?

Comment: @phd It's not ignoring files even I edit like this so I thought my question is not **answerable**.